# The POST method is not supported for route tickets/BDkkh9ef. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I want to submit a form using `.on('submit', function (event)` I get this error and can't figure out why. the error shows for all these tickets route not just the example I am posting.

Here is the route part:

```
Route::post('tickets/update', [SupportTicketController::class, 'update'])->name('tickets.update');
Route::resource('tickets', SupportTicketController::class)->except(['destroy', 'create', 'update']);
Route::post('tickets/{ticket}/assigned', [EmployeeAssignedController::class, 'employeeTicketAssigned'])->name('tickets.assigned');
Route::get('tickets/{id}/delete', [SupportTicketController::class, 'destroy'])->name('tickets.destroy');
Route::get('tickets/download/{id}', [SupportTicketController::class, 'download'])->name('tickets.downloadTicket');
Route::post('tickets/delete/selected', [SupportTicketController::class, 'delete_by_selection'])->name('mass_delete_tickets');
Route::post('tickets/{ticket}/comments', [SupportTicketCommentController::class, 'index'])->name('ticket_comments.index');
Route::post('tickets/store_comments/{ticket}', [SupportTicketCommentController::class, 'store'])->name('ticket_comments.store');
Route::get('tickets/{id}/delete_comments', [SupportTicketCommentController::class, 'destroy'])->name('ticket_comments.destroy');
Route::post('tickets/{ticket}/details', [SupportTicketController::class, 'detailsStore'])->name('ticket_details.store');
Route::post('tickets/{ticket}/notes', [SupportTicketController::class, 'notesStore'])->name('ticket_notes.store');
```

view javascript example:

```
$('#assigned_form').on('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('tickets.assigned',$ticket) }}",
    method: "post",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        let html = '';
        if (data.errors) {
            html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
            for (let count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++) {
                html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
            }
            html += '</div>';
        }
        if (data.success) {
            html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
        }
        $('#assigned_result').html(html).slideDown(300).delay(500).slideUp(300);
    }
})

});
```

and this is the route is calling:

```
class EmployeeAssignedController extends Controller {

 public function employeeTicketAssigned(Request $request, SupportTicket $ticket)
 {
     $role = Role::find(Auth::user()->role_id);
     if($role->hasPermissionTo('assign-ticket'))
     {
         $employees = $request->input('employee_id');
         $ticket->assignedEmployees()->sync($employees);
         $notificable = User::where('role_id', 1)
            ->orWhere('id', $ticket->employee->id)
            ->orWhere('id', $ticket->customer->id)
            ->orwhereIntegerInRaw('id', $employees)
            ->get();
         Notification::send($notificable, new TicketAssignedNotification($ticket));

         return response()->json(['success' => __('تم إدخال البيانات بنجاح')]);
    }

     return response()->json(['success' => __('غير مصرح لك')]);
 }

}
```

Comment: Is there difference if you set `Route::resource(…)` at the end of all routes which consider tickets?

Comment: I did that and it worked for all routes except this one     Route::post('tickets/{ticket}/assigned', [EmployeeAssignedController::class, 'employeeTicketAssigned'])->name('tickets.assigned');

Comment: I also noticed that the route is POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/tickets/BDkkh9ef not POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/tickets/BDkkh9ef/assigned

Answer (score 0):

Seem you didn't pass second argument for route.

For example

```
Route::get('/post/{post}/comment/{comment}', function () {
    //
})->name('comment.show');

route('comment.show', ['post' => 1, 'comment' => 3]);
```

In your case, it could be

```
url: "{{ route('tickets.assigned', ['ticket' => $ticket]) }}",
```

Comment: I do pass it in the Ajax function, despite writing it differently, I tried to write it your way but still got the same issue.

Comment: Can you just call the endpoint from postman ?

Comment: I installed postman and and made a new http request using this link http://127.0.0.1:8000/tickets/BDkkh9ef. what is the endpoint tho?

Comment: Can you try after rename the route. I guess, it's conflict with Route::resource. Or you can try comment out the resources.

Comment: I renamed it, didn't work. I also made sure it support post
POST  tickets/{ticket}/assigned  tickets.assigned  EmployeeAssignedController@employeeTicketAssigned

I checked the network tab in the console and the header is empty, idk why.

Summary
URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tickets/BDkkh9ef
Status: —
Source: —

Request
No request headers

Response
No response headers

Answer (score 0):

use below command in cmd
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear

Comment: it could be precise with php artisan route:cache

Comment: check your route that defined as post route. ```Route::post(....```